If a woman falsely attributes a child to her husband, while he does not know the truth, is it a sin on her?

The Prophet  sallallaahu  `alayhi  wa  sallam ( may  Allaah exalt his
mention ) said: “Any woman who falsely attributes her child to a
people to whom he does not belong, she has no relation to (the
religion of) Allah.” [Abu Daawood and An-Nasaa’i]

Although the wording of the Hadeeth is about women, the ruling applies to men as well. If the husband becomes certain that this woman has committed adultery and falsely attributed her illegitimate child to him and he refrains from denying the paternity of the child, then he would be falsely attributing to himself a child that is not his. Accordingly, he becomes subject to the warning stated in the Hadeeth. This is in addition to the consequences of not denying the paternity of the illegitimate child with regard to rights as he would unjustly take part of his legitimate children’s rights.
It was given in a fatwa-
https://www.islamweb.net/en/fatwa/406384/husband-abroad-for-3-years-and-once-he-arrived-wife-had-baby
So if my understanding is correct,
Let's consider a scenario, a wife becomes pregnant by Zina, to hide her sins she attributes the child to her husband, while the husband is not aware of the fact that it is not his child. So, will she be under the wrath of Allah(swt)? Am also curious that will such things be put on trial or be exposed to the husband in judgement day?
Edit: Also the Hadeeth in which the Prophet said “He who deceives is not one of us” is an authentic Hadeeth narrated byMuslim, Abu Daawood, At-Tirmidhi, Ibn Maajah and others may also imply that it is a sin to cheat a person.

If anyone can even give any leads in the comments, that is also appreciated
